# Missing Wifi in iMac 2011

Tags: wifi, imac, airport

I recently re-built the iMac 2011 by taking it all apart, cleaning and adding new hard disk and fresh install of High Sierra.

I am however unable to get any sort of wifi or even ethernet! This is quite strange! I want to know if there is a way to detect what components are attached to the iMac, like the list of components in Device Manager in Windows?

I want to see if Airport card is detected or not. I double checked the three wirings online as follows and they are attached same way using markings.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know if there is a way to detect what components are attached to the iMac, like the list of components in Device Manager in Windows?

**Yes.** If you click on the **`Apple`** logo in the upper left corner of your screen, select **`About This Mac`**. You will be greeted by a new window, showing some basic information. To get a detailed list about connected components and more, click **`System Report`**. Unfold the section **`Hardware`** and you will find e.g `Ethernet-cards` or under **`Network`** it should list `WiFi` and display (in my case) an `AirPort Extreme` card.

If you want to read more about system report, head over to [Apple support site](https://support.apple.com/de-de/guide/system-information/syspr35536/mac).

---

If you haven't done so, I would also try resetting SMC/NVRAM, boot in safe-mode and try the hardware test. Read more about the [startup options](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255) on Apples support page.

Comment: ok, I was able to follow your steps. It looks like there is no AirPort card! So does this mean my card is corrupted? I however do have bluetooth working! Apparently the same AirPort card provides bluetooth as well. Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Please edit your question so that other don't have to dig through comments to find very helpful info. If it is not being detected by the system it means it is either not connected properly or broken. Yet, if you are absolutely sure Bluetooth works fine and is being handled by the same card, it sounds to me like the WiFi capabilities of the card are corrupted, either due to wrong cabling or something inside the card.

Answer (score 0):

The `networksetup` utility would be a good place to start. (`networksetup -help`)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. If possible, it'd be good if you could add some more info on how the user can use this to help them solve the problem? Also, you may want to read [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for tips on providing answers here.